# 406 (Inacceptable) error with ajax and spring mvc

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

i have this problem `GET http://localhost:8080/yous/ajaxtest 406 (Inacceptable)`
There is my script i use ajax to handle a login form:

```
        function ajaxtest() {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'ajaxtest',
            success : function(responce) {
                if(responce)
                    $('#formlogin').submit();
                else
                $('#errorlogin').html("Le nom d'utilisateur ou le mot de passe saisi est incorrect.");
            }
        });
       }
```

My controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxtest")
    public @ResponseBody
    boolean  ajaxtest(@ModelAttribute(value="auth") Auth auth) {

    List<Auth> listlogin = authDao.findByProperty("login", auth.getLogin(), "pwd", auth.getPwd());
    if(listlogin.size() == 1)
        return true;    
    return false;
    }
```

A another question i'm new with ajax and i hear a lot of JSON to send request is he the best way to deal with ajax ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just add this dependency and it's work :)

```
    <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

When your handler method is annotated with `@ResponseBody`, Spring will typically produce a JSON response body setting the response `content-type` to `application/json`. If you don't have an `Accept` header for that media type in your request, Spring will deem the response Unacceptable and return an 406 error code.

You need to specify the `Accept` header in your ajax request

```
headers: { 
    Accept : "application/json"
}
```

Use the media type that is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem when i send an address email using GET method. i resolved my issue by using POST method